# JavaFX not finding all system fonts

Tags: java, javafx, fonts

I've noticed that the JavaFX components I use, unlike their Swing counterparts, are not rendering some system fonts properly. Here's the complete example that presents the issue.

```
public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Swing button
        SwingNode node = new SwingNode();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JButton swingButton = new JButton("Comic Sans MS");
            swingButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 20));
            node.setContent(swingButton);
        });

        // JavaFX button
        Button fxButton = new Button("Comic Sans MS");
        fxButton.setFont(Font.font("Comic Sans MS", 20));

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(node, fxButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Font test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you have the Comic Sans MS font in your system, you should see the following result. Only the Swing component looks fine:

[image: Broken fonts]

Apparently the FX graphics system does not load all system fonts on startup. The most obvious solution is to load the missing ones manually, like that:

```
Font.loadFont(new FileInputStream(System.getenv("WINDIR")+"\\fonts\\"+"comic.ttf"), 20);
```

Now everything renders properly, but this solution isn't cross platform and I'd really expect it to work out-of-the-box just like it was in Swing. Am I missing something? If not, then why only a subset of system fonts is loaded into the JavaFX environment?

I'm running it on Windows 10.

Comment: Im a little unsure about this one as i was unable to replicate your problem on windows however it may be OS specific since windows 7 may already have the Comic-sans font available for java-fx on load however you could try Font.getFontNames() and see what fonts are available and maybe load them in loop in a similar way as this for awt http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Togetallavailablefontsinyoursystem.htm

Comment: @Dean219 - thanks, I forgot to mention that I run it on Windows 10. If it works on Windows 7 then perhaps it's an OS specific bug.

Comment: Well it worked for me it may not for others but i would guess that since you can load specific system fonts it may only load some of what's available and not every single font which may be the issue, maybe if windows 10 has more varied fonts then comic sans is not a default font that it loads so it may be a recreateable issue on windows 10 but you should try printing what fonts are available using the Font class and seeing if it's on the list and see if there are others that are on the list that work without specifically calling them.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another thing: I created following code

```
String fonts[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailab‌​leFontFamilyNames(); for(String font: fonts) { System.out.printf("This is font %s %n", font);
```

This returns for example: This is font Something Strange (its a font which i downloaded and installed) so its available. But when I put it into this code:

```
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10"
      style="-fx-font-family: Something Strange">
```

The text does not change at all. Maybe this contribute to your / our problem.

Comment: Ymm, since it's not an answer to my question, I think you should post it as a comment, or leave it as it is since our questions are linked already.

Comment: Ah ok you can link it didn't know that. Sorry that I posted it as an answer. Still getting used to stackoverflow.